# How can I get Safari to show the Javascript sources when debugging Jitsi?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-web-inspector

I'm working on getting Safari support working in Jitsi. To track down the issues, it would help to be able to set breakpoints. To set breakpoints, I need to open the source files. However, Safari is not showing the Javascript source files. What can I do to make it show them?[image: ipts]

To see the problem, try inspecting at https://meet.jit.si/LegendaryGentlemenFitPerhaps for example.